# Vertex positions appearing incorrectly when applying a stride to glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: c++, opengl

I ran into an issue where my vertices were being drawn offscreen. I changed the stride to 0 for all my vertex attribute pointers and now they draw at the correct location.

Here is some code to start this off:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexID);
glBindVertexArray(vertexID);

glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);


GLfloat verts[4 * 2 * 3] = { -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0,// bottom left
                        .5, -.5, 0.0, 1.0,    // bottom right
                        -.5, .5, 0.0, 1.0,    // top left
                        0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0,
                        .5, -.5, 0.0, 1.0,    // bottom right
                        -.5, .5, 0.0, 1.0,    // top left// top right
                        };
GLfloat color[4 * 3 * 2] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

GLfloat tex[8] = {
1.0f, 1.0f, 
1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f
};

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts) + sizeof(color) + sizeof(tex), nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(verts), verts);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), sizeof(color), color);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts) + sizeof(color), sizeof(tex), tex);


glClearColor(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f);







glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 10, NULL);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 10, (const GLvoid *)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 4));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 10, (const GLvoid *)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 8));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

GLuint indices[4] = {
    0,2,1,3
};
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

and then here is the rendering code

```
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glBindVertexArray(vertexID);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glFlush();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

Okay so here is where I am confused:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 10, NULL);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 10, (const GLvoid *)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 4));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 10, (const GLvoid *)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 8));
```

With this above code, the program doesn't render the proper square I am trying to render. If I change the stride to 0 for all of these, then it renders in the correct position. My understanding of it was that i sub buffered 3 sets of information: position, color, and tex coordinates. Therefor I thought the data looked like the following:
[image]

There for I set the stride to sizeof(GLFloat) * 10, however, this doesn't work. This makes me assume I also don't have the offset values set correctly. **So why is my stride messing up the vertex position?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefor I thought the data looked like the following:

But that's not what you told OpenGL.

> ```
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(verts), verts);
> ```

This tells OpenGL to take the array `verts` and copy it into the start of the buffer object.

> ```
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), sizeof(color), color);
> ```

This tells OpengL to take the array `color`, and copy it into the buffer object, but after *all of `verts`*.

There's no interleaving here. You buffer stores all of `verts`, followed by all of `color`, followed by all of `tex`. It does not store 4 floats of `verts` followed by 4 floats of `color`, followed by 4 floats of `tex`.

`glBufferSubData` cannot interleave data for you (well, you could do it in a long series of calls, but that'd be ridiculous). If you want to upload interleaved vertex data, *you* have to interleave it on the CPU, then upload it.

And setting the strides to 0 doesn't make this work. Well, it doesn't make it work *correctly*. Your base offsets are still wrong, relative to the data you actually uploaded. You'll get the correct position data, but the colors and texture coordinates will be wrong.

Comment: Yes I didn't realize changing to subBuffer was not interleaving the data for some reason.. So now i do 
sizeof(verts) then
sizeof(verts) + sizeof(color) for my offsets... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're uploading your vertex data in blocks:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts) + sizeof(color) + sizeof(tex), nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(verts), verts);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), sizeof(color), color);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts) + sizeof(color), sizeof(tex), tex);
```

So it ends up like:

```
<vert 0, ... vert N><color 0, ..., color N><tex 0, ..., tex N>
```

But your `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls are claiming the buffer is interleaved like this:

```
<vert 0><color 0><tex 0><vert 1><color1><tex 1>...
```

Either interleave the data at upload or adjust your `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls to take into account the block layout.